# Long time before PSH,ACK is received

Tags: google-chrome, http, tcp, package, handshake

I have a client and a server and there is a problem, which I will specify after the packet exchange.

Note: the server serves a html file with an image

```
> SYN
< SYN, ACK
> ACK
> PSH, ACK (request of html file)
< PSH, ACK (html file)
> ACK
< FIN, ACK
```

This all goes fine, but now the client wants the image that is in the html file, so it initiates a new TCP handshake:

```
> SYN
< SYN, ACK
> ACK
delay of over 4 seconds here
> PSH, ACK (request of image)
< PSH, ACK (image)
> ACK
< FIN, ACK
```

The client is using google chrome. The request of the html page takes 1400ms, the request of the image however, takes up to 8000ms, due to the client waiting  a long time to send PSH, ACK.

Why does it take so long? Is it due to chrome or something externally?

Comment: You should at least try Firefox to see if this is Chrome specific.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson I just tested, it's exactly the same response as chrome.

Comment: At least you know now that the problem isn't in the client software (Chrome).